# Glob regex patterns - PHP

Tags: php, regex, glob

I have folder that has multiple images but I'm interested with images that title like : `"Images_123456_nature_XL.jpg, Images_458599_3d_L.jpg, Images_065455_animals_XL.jpg"`. So try the `glob` function like this :

```
$images = glob($value."/^Images_(\d+)_([a-zA-Z]+)_([A-Z]+).{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

But it doesn't seem to work.Any help with this! Much appreciated.

Comment: Glob doesn't take regex. It takes a mask. `glob($value."/Images_*.{jpg,png,gif}",GLOB_BRACE)` might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) doesn't take regular expressions, it takes simple patterns, only replacing * jokers by anything, and ? by a single character.

You can try with something like:

```
$files = array_filter(glob('*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE), function($file) {
  return preg_match('/^Images_(\d+)_([a-zA-Z]+)_([A-Z]+)\.(jpg|png|gif)$/', basename($file));
});
```

This is not really efficient in term of memory (as glob() will return all files before you filter it), but this works, at least.